# Is it safe to add our custom indexes to optimize agent?

Tags: solr

There is a `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Tasks.Optimize` agent defined in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
Definition looks like this:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Tasks.Optimize" method="Run" interval="12:00:00">
  <indexes hint="list">
    <index>sitecore_master_index</index>
  </indexes>
</agent>
```

It only contains `sitecore_master_index` inside `indexes` list.

My questions:

- Why there is only master index added to the list and there are no other indexes like web or marketing?
- Is it recommended to add our custom indexes here to the list?
- Is it safe to optimize index that is used on web? Is it still searchable and operable?

Comment: Don't optimize at all: https://lucidworks.com/2017/10/13/segment-merging-deleted-documents-optimize-may-bad/

Comment: Thanks it is really great article, it explains a lot. But looks like it could be still beneficial to optimize indexes when they are relatively small, like less 1GB in total?

Comment: During optimization, huge number of IO operations is performed. Your queries will be much slower, new indexing indexing will be slower as well. What do you need to optimize? performance-wise your index won't be much faster. Do you need to reduce disk space?

Comment: I was just curious why master index is optimized by agent and other indexes are not and if it safe to add other indexes here. The article you provided explains a lot. Our indexes are quite small, like less than 1GB each. In that case optimisation is quite fast, like less than 2 min and maybe during night it could be beneficial for us to execute it? On the other hand if it is not, then maybe we should remove the master index from this agent as well.

Comment: I converted my comments into an answer and replied to your last question there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't optimize at all.** Here is a very good article about optimization of lucene indexes:

https://lucidworks.com/2017/10/13/segment-merging-deleted-documents-optimize-may-bad/

During optimization, huge number of IO operations is performed. Your queries will be much slower, new indexing indexing will be slower as well. What do you need to optimize? Performance-wise your index won't be much faster. And space on your hard drive is cheap.

Why the "master" index is optimized? I guess the question should be:

> "Why **only** master index is optimized?".

I don't work at Sitecore so I cannot be sure, but I would say that it's because this index is not used from your CD servers so it should have minimal impact on your end users. Your content editors will survive if authoring experience is a bit slower.

Comment: Additional supporting material specific to Sitecore and the Optimize function: https://grantkillian.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/the-solr-optimize-now-button-for-sitecore-use-cases/

Comment: @GKillian good article. Thanks for adding the comment

Comment: Marek thanks for answer and @GKillian thanks for this additional link.